# N-dimensional Circles!

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a program that takes two numbers as its input. The first one is the number of dimensions - 0 for a dot, 1 for a straight line, 2 for a circle, 3 for a sphere. The second number is the radius of the object, or, if it's 1-dimensional, the number itself. Output 0 for 0 dimensions. The output is the length/area/volume of the object.

If we call the first number `n`, the second one `r`, and the output `x`, we get that:

- for n = 0, x = 1
- for n = 1, x = 2×r
- for n = 2, x = r<sup>2</sup>×π
- for n = 3, x = (<sup>4</sup>/<sub>3</sub>)×r<sup>3</sup>×π
- and so on... if you want, though.

Notes:

- Cases when one or both numbers are negative, or when the first number is not whole, don't need to be covered.
- The program must not read from any file and the only input are those two numbers.
- The output should use only numerals (e.g. not "14*pi"), and should be accurate to at least two decimal digits.
- As for n = 0, you can output 0 if it makes the code shorter.
- **Extra swag for an answer covering even 4 and more-dimensional "spheres"!**
- It's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Examples:

```
 1 1 -> 2

 2 3 -> 28,27

 3 1 -> 4,19

 3 4,5 -> 381,70

 1 9.379 -> 18.758

 0 48 -> 1
```

Comment: Yay! I love false MathJax equations in posts!

Comment: Should we output `0` or `1` for *n* = 0?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 You should output `1`, but if it would be really extending your code, you can add a solution with `0` to your answer.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Sorry, no, you can't. BTW it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: Not to critic, but I don't see how a line can be considered as a 1d circle...

Comment: @xem Consider a circle as all points that are within a given distance from the center

Comment: Math types would call these "balls" of various dimensions.  The set of points with distance from the origin `== r` is the sphere, the set of points with distance from the origin `<= r` is the ball.  Then these are 0-ball = point, 1-ball = segment, 2-ball = disk, 3-ball = ball, 4-ball, 5-ball, et c. (listed as "`n`-ball = common name").

Comment: "Output 0 for 0 dimensions" and "for n = 0, x = 1" contradict each other. Could you please choose one (or clarify that both are allowed)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) + extra swag

```
÷2µØP*÷!
ç×*@
```

**[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7cywrXDmFAqw7chCsOnw5cqQA&input=&args=Mw+NC41)**

Works for any dimension, so long as the fixed value of π yielded by `ØP` (`3.141592653589793`) is accurate enough.

#### How?

```
÷2µØP*÷! - Link 1: n, r
÷2       - n / 2
  µ      - monadic chain separation
   ØP    - π (3.141592653589793)
     *   - exponentiate: π^(n/2)
       ! - Pi(n/2): Gamma(n/2 + 1)
      ÷  - divide: π^(n/2) / Gamma(n/2 + 1)

ç×*@     - Main link: n, r
ç        - call last link (1) as a dyad: π^(n/2) / Gamma(n/2 + 1)
  *@     - exponentiate with reversed @rguments: r^n
 ×       - multiply: r^n * π^(n/2) / Gamma(n/2 + 1)
```

Comment: Well done for beating Mathematica!

Comment: Congrats, you won!

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica, 18 bytes, up to ~168.15 trillion dimensions

```
Pi^(a=.5#)/a!#2^#&
```

Anonymous function. Takes two numbers as input, and returns an inexact number as output. Works with any number of dimensions. Outputs `1.` for *n* = 0. Uses the formula from [Volume of an n-ball](http://enwp.org/Volume_of_an_n-ball) on Wikipedia.

#### Explanation

We are attempting to compute π<sup>*n*/2</sup>/*Γ*(*n*/2 + 1)·*R*<sup>*n*</sup>, or `N[Pi^(n/2)/Gamma[n/2 + 1] R^n]` in Mathematica. In our case, `#` (first argument) is *n* and `#2` (second argument) is *R*. This leaves us with `N[Pi^(#/2)/Gamma[#/2 + 1] #2^#] &`, which can be golfed as follows:

```
N[Pi^(#/2)/Gamma[#/2 + 1] #2^#] &
Pi^(.5#)/Gamma[.5# + 1] #2^# &    (* replace exact with approximate numbers*)
Pi^(.5#)/(.5#)! #2^# &            (* n! == Gamma[n + 1] *)
Pi^(a=.5#)/a! #2^# &              (* replace repeated .5# *)
Pi^(a=.5#)/a!#2^#&                (* remove whitespace *)
```

and thus, our original program.

Comment: Nice answer - that was fast! Just for clarification: To how many digits is the output correct? How many dimensions it's possible to calculate?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek It outputs to about 5 significant figures, and it works for all *n* up to 168,146,894,169,516 for *r* = 1 (albeit with less figures).

Comment: @LegionMammal978 which formula? I'm quite certain you don't use the gamma function there

Comment: @Angs *n*! = *Γ* ( *n* + 1).

Comment: Could you please ungolf and explain each part of the code? Some less experienced users maybe don't see what's in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, `!` works for non-integrals too. Using Mathematica for this almost feels like cheating… :)

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>75</s> <s>40</s> 38 bytes (plus extra swag)

Well, looks like I could golf this down by giving in and using the gamma function rather than recursive functions.

```
function(n,r)pi^(n/2)/gamma(n/2+1)*r^n
```

Defines an anonymous function to calculate the volume of an `n`-dimensional hypersphere of radius `r`.

Some examples:

> 1 1 -> 2
>
> 0 48 ->  1
>
> 2 3 -> 28.27433
>
> 3 4.5 -> 381.7035
>
> 7 7 -> 3891048
>
> 100 3 -> 122051813

## Swagless solution, <s>38</s> 34 bytes

For a few bytes less, you can have an anonymous function that only works for dimensions 1 to 3. Returns `numeric(0)` for `n=0`, and `NA` for `n>3`. (`numeric(0)` is a numeric vector of length 0; `NA` is for "not available".) Performance is otherwise identical to the general solution above.

```
function(n,r)c(1,pi,4/3*pi)[n]*r^n
```

Comment: ₊₁ for the SSSSSWWWWWAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGG!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes + extra swag

Recursive formula from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Volume_of_an_n-ball&section=3#Recursions), should work for any number of dimension

```js
f=(n,r)=>n<2?n?2*r:1:f(n-2,r)*2*Math.PI*r*r/n
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>61</s> <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 43 bytes

**0-3 dimensions are supported because [there is no 4th dimension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9sbdrPVfOQ)**.

Thanks to @Hedi for saving 7 bytes

```
d=(n,r)=>r**n*(n<2?n+1:Math.PI*(n<3?1:4/3))
```

Creates function `d`. Then raises `r` to the `n`th power and then multiplies it with a number depending on `n` using ternary operators. Outputs `1` for `n=0`

Gives output to at least 2 decimal places (10+ dp)

### Here's a snack snippet!

```js
var N = document.getElementById("n");
var R = document.getElementById("r");
N.value="3";//default
R.value="4.5";//default
d=(n,r)=>r**n*(n<2?n+1:Math.PI*(n<3?1:4/3));
var b = document.getElementById("b");
b.onclick = function() {
  var s = document.getElementById("s");
  var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
  var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
  s.textContent = d(parseFloat(n),parseFloat(r));
}
```

```css
span {border:1px solid black;padding:10px;font-size:30px;}
```

```html
Value of n: <input id="n" type="number"></input>
Value of r: <input id="r" type="number"></input><br>
<button id="b">Calculate!</button><br><br><br>
<span id="s">THERE IS NO 4TH DIMENSION</span>
```

Comment: Beat my non-posted solution by... by a lot. +1!

Comment: what a dumb video…

Comment: @SargeBorsch At least it proves my point :)

Comment: You can save bytes using Math.PI only once and you can make n<1 and n<2 the same case (will return `1` for `n=0`) `d=(n,r)=>r**n*(n<2?n+1:Math.PI*(n<3?1:4/3))`

Comment: @Hedi Thanks! You saved me 7 bytes!

Comment: @SargeBorsch Haha yup dumb video - 0:40 `3 dimensions that behave in the same way and one that behaves in a different way` - At that point he seems to be saying there is a 4th dimension, but no 1st, 2nd or 3rd!

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Well that was the first result I was on the web ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>74</s> <s>65</s> 36 bytes + extra swag

```
0%r=1
1%r=2*r
n%r=2*pi*r^2/n*(n-2)%r
```

Recursive formula, works for all dimensions that can be presented exactly as a double-precision floating point number but will loop infinitely for non-integral dimensions. The old version for posteriority's sake:

```
n%r=(max 1$1-(-1)**n)*(2*pi)^(floor$n/2)*r**n/product[n,n-2..1.1]
```

<s>Works for all dimensions. Uses the formula from [the tau manifesto](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto#sec-volume_of_a_hypersphere).
`product[n,n-2..1.1]` is a [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) hack that won't count zero for `n==2`</s>

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
3:^[2P4*P/3]*1hi)
```

This works up to 3 dimensions only. Inputs are in reverse order, that is: `r`, then `n`.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MzpeWzJQNCpQLzNdKjFoaSk&input=Mwoy)

Consider `r=3`, `n=2` as an example.

```
3:         % Push array [1 2 3]
           % STACK: [1 2 3]
^          % Take r implicitly, and raise it to [1 2 3] element-wise
           % STACK: [3 9 27]
[2P4*P/3]  % Push array [2 pi 4*pi/3]
           % STACK: [3 9 27], [2 pi 4*pi/3]
*          % Multiply element-wise
           % STACK: [6 28.2743 113.0973]
1h         % Append 1
           % STACK: [6 28.2743 113.0973, 1]
i)         % Input n and use it as modular index into the array. Display implicitly
           % STACK: 28.2743
```

Answer (score 2):

### Racket 69 bytes (plus extra swag)

Uses recursive formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Volume_of_an_n-ball&section=3#Recursions

Including suggestions by @wchargin

```
(define(v d r)(match d[0 1][1(* 2 r)][_(/(* 2 pi r r(v(- d 2)r))d)]))
```

Ungolfed (v=volume, d=dimensions, r=radius):

```
(define(v d r)
  (match d
    [0 1]
    [1 (* 2 r)]
    [_ (/ (*  2   pi   r   r   (v (- d 2) r)  )
          d)]
    ))
```

Testing:

```
(v 1 1)
(v 2 3)
(v 3 1)
(v 3 4.5)
(v 1 9.379)
(v 0 48)
```

Output:

```
2
28.274333882308138
4.1887902047863905
381.7035074111599
18.758
1
```

Comment: I highly doubt that this is legitimate: you're using the recursive function without counting its definition in the byte count. That is, the expression that you're scoring as 67 bytes is not valid Racket, as `v` is unbound (not to mention the other parameters). Surely you need to count the `(define(v d r))` as well? This brings you up to 82 bytes…

Comment: …but you can shave off four bytes from that by replacing your `cond` with nested `if` expressions, bringing you down to 78 bytes with `(define(v d r)(if(= d 0)1(if(= d 1)(* 2 r)(*(/(* 2 pi(* r r))d)(v(- d 2)r)))))`.

Comment: …and shave off three more by using a `match` to get `(define(v d r)(match d[0 1][1(* 2 r)][_(*(/(* 2 pi(* r r))d)(v(- d 2)r))]))`.

Comment: Thanks for great suggestions. I am including these in the answer.

Comment: @wchargin : I could reduce 9 more bytes by repositioning (v (- d 2) r) in formula and by using only "r r" instead of "(* r r)" since it is already in a multiplication formula.

Answer (score 2):

### Java/C/C++/C#, <strike>69</strike> 67 bytes + extra swag!

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @AlexRacer

A dyadic function - first argument is number of dimensions, second is the radius of the n-ball.

`float v(int n,float r){return n<1?1:n<2?2*r:6.283f*r*r*v(n-2,r)/n;}`

Recursive formula for the volume of an n-ball:
V<sub>n</sub>=<sup>(2πr<sup>2</sup>V<sub>n-2</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>

Whoa! Java (my test language) beats Scala here, thanks to the terse `?:` ternary syntax! This function is syntactically correct in all 4 languages in the heading, and I have tested it with C (MinGW GCC 5.4.0), & C# (VS Ultimate 2016, C# 6.0). I'm assuming that it will work in C++ too, so there. Since this function is pretty much library-independent, it should work in any C-like language with similar syntax.

Comment: Wow! I thought I'd never get a Java answer! Got it - thanks! And, as a bonus, it beat some answers **and** got the extra swag! ₊₁

Comment: `n==0` can be shortened to `n<1` and also `n==1` to `n<2`

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <strike>52 bytes for tab indent</strike> 42 bytes + extra swag

Edit: Saved 10 bytes thanks to @WChargin

A dyadic curried function - first argument is number of dimensions, second is the radius of the n-ball.

```
v 0 r=1
v 1 r=2*r
v n r=2*pi*r*r*v(n-2)r/n
```

Recursive formula for the volume of an n-ball:
V<sub>n</sub>=<sup>(2πr<sup>2</sup>V<sub>n-2</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>

Save this as a separate script file and run with GHCi, with a function for testing `v` for output, e.g., `show (v 3 4.5)`. I did not test this, please let me know if this doesn't work.

Old program with 6.2832 approximation for 2π replaced (50 bytes with tab indent):

```
let v 0 r=1
    v 1 r=2*r
    v n r=2*pi*r*r*(v(n-2)r)/n
```

This can be used with GHCi in multiline mode (using `:set +m` or enclosing the code between `:{` & `:}`, the enclosures being on their own lines. Tester function required.

Static typing with full-program type inference comes into play here, allowing Haskell to do far better than Scala, and approaching Groovy, but not quite beating it thanks to the pattern match instead of a ternary, involving some character repetition.

Comment: 51 if using layout directly, 49 if you substitute `2*pi` for `6.2832`, and 47 if you drop the parentheses around the recursive call: `let{v 0 r=1;v 1 r=2*r;v n r=2*pi*r*r*v(n-2)r/n}`…

Comment: …but more typical scoring is to submit as a separate script file; drop the `let{}` and replace my semicolons with linefeeds to get just 42 bytes (without trailing newline).

Comment: @WChargin I've been learning Haskell for a whole 2 days, so thanks for the pointers. I erred on the side of caution with the parentheses as I'm not sure about operator vs function call precedence in Haskell

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, <s>76</s> <s>72</s> 68 bytes + extra swag!

Recursive solution with extra swag!
Returns `0` for `n=0`

```
from math import*
f=lambda n,r:n*r*2*(n<2or pi*r/n/n*(f(n-2,r)or 1))
```

Old approach (`1` for `n=1`):

```
from math import*
f=lambda n,r:1*(n<1)or r*2*(n<2)or 2*pi*r*r/n*f(n-2,r)
```

Recursive formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Recursions).

[Try it online.](https://repl.it/EPk2/0)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 56 bytes + extra swag!

Straightforward with extra swag!

```
from math import*
lambda n,r:pi**(n/2)*r**n/gamma(n/2+1)
```

[Standard formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#The_volume)

[Try it online](https://repl.it/EPgY/1)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 63 bytes + extra swag

```
@a=1..2;push@a,6.283/$_*@a[$_-2]for 2..($b=<>);say$a[$b]*<>**$b
```

Accepts two integers n and r, one at a time, then outputs the n-volume for given radius r of an n-sphere.  When n = 0, V = 1, and when n = 1, V = 2r.  All further dimensions are calculated by the following formula:

[image: Recursive volume formula]

Since r<sup>n</sup> is the radius's factor in every formula, I leave it out of the base calculation and only apply it at the end.

2π is approximated in the code by 6.283.

Comment: Nice and recursive, and ₊₁ for showing the recursive formula.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 53 bytes

```
{import math._;(n,r)=>pow(r,n)*Seq(1,2,Pi,Pi*4/3)(n)}
```

Sorry, no extra swag for me :(

Explanation:

```
{                     //define a block, the type of this is the type of the last expression, which is a function
  import math._;        //import everything from math, for pow and pi
  (n,r)=>               //define a function
    pow(r,n)*             //r to the nth power multiplied by
    Seq(1,2,Pi,Pi*4/3)(n) //the nth element of a sequence of 1, 2, Pi and Pi*4/3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes, no swag

```
(n,r)=>[1,r+r,a=Math.PI*r*r,a*r*4/3][n]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, <strike>49</strike> 47 bytes + extra swag!

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @AlexRacer

A dyadic function - first argument is number of dimensions, second is the radius of the n-ball.

`def v(n,r){n<1?1:n<2?2*r:6.2832*r*r*v(n-2,r)/n}`

Recursive formula for the volume of an n-ball:
V<sub>n</sub>=<sup>(2πr<sup>2</sup>V<sub>n-2</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>

Dynamic Typing FTW!

My Scala and Java answers use the same logic, but with static typing so higher byte counts due to type annotations :(. However, Scala and Groovy allow me to omit the `return` and the semicolon, so that helps the byte count, unlike Java/C...

Comment: ₊₁ for the extra SWAG!

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <strike>81</strike> 79 bytes + extra swag!

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @AlexRacer

A dyadic function - first argument is number of dimensions, second is the radius of the n-ball.

`def v(n:Int,r:Float):Float=if n<1 1 else if n<2 2*r else 6.2832f*r*r*v(n-2,r)/n`

Recursive formula for the volume of an n-ball:
V<sub>n</sub>=<sup>(2πr<sup>2</sup>V<sub>n-2</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>n</sub>

Scala's lack of type inference for return types of recursive functions and function parameters and verbose ternary syntax hurts quite a bit here :(

Answer (score 1):

## [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 96 characters + extra swag

Line split in 2 for readability:

```
#N,R::((if (< N 2) ((? (!= 0 N) (* 2 R) 1)) ((/ (* (* (* (* (f (- N 2) R) 2)
        3.1416) R) R) N))))
```

Thinking I need to upgrade my parser to require less spaces. Code size would be cut down nicely, especially in that `((/ (* (* (* (*` section.

Usage:

```
% n-circle.lithp
(
    (def f #N,R::((if (< N 2) ((? (!= 0 N) (* 2 R) 1)) ((/ (* (* (* (* (f (- N 2) R) 2) 3.1416) R) R) N)))))
    (print (f 1 1))
    (print (f 2 3))
    (print (f 3 1))
    (print (f 3 4.5))
    (print (f 1 9.379))
    (print (f 0 48))
)

#./run.js n-circle.lithp
2
28.274333882308138
4.1887902047863905
381.7035074111598
18.758
1
```

Thanks to Rudolf for shaving a few bytes off.

Comment: What about shortening "`3.141592653589793`" to "`3.1416`", saving 11 bytes and still fitting into the rules?

Answer (score 1):

### CJam (27 bytes with extra credit)

```
{1$_[2dP]*<f*\,:)-2%./1+:*}
```

[Online test suite](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B%5B1%201%5D%5B2%203%5D%5B3%201%5D%5B3%204.5%5D%5B1%209.379%5D%5B0%2048%5D%5D%7B~%0A%0A%7B1%24_%5B2dP%5D*%3Cf*%5C%2C%3A)-2%25.%2F1%2B%3A*%7D%0A%0A~p%7D%2F). This is an anonymous block (function) which takes arguments `d r` on the stack and leaves the result on the stack.

#### Dissection

The general n-dimensional formula can be rewritten as

$$\frac{2^{\left\lceil\frac{d}{2}\right\rceil}\pi^{\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2}\right\rfloor} r^d}{d!!}$$

```
{            e# Begin block: stack holds d r
  1$_[2dP]*< e#   Build a list which repeats [2 pi] d times and take the first d elements
  f*         e#   Multiply each element of the list by r
  \,:)-2%    e#   Build a list [1 ... d] and take every other element starting at the end
  ./         e#   Pointwise divide. The d/2 elements of the longer list are untouched
  1+:*       e#   Add 1 to ensure the list is non-empty and multiply its elements
}
```